# How C++11 has changed the standard containers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++11

I get that C++ 11 has introduced the new move semantics and as consequence data containers are changed to meet the new definitions and specifications of the language, I don't really get how the standard containers benefits from them.

Also I think that I have got what an Rvalue is and how the move semantics act, the problem is i don't see any useful point about this, moving things and changing their labels doesn't sound like a meaningful feature.

I can ask for a good resource about how `map, list, vector, ...` are changing in the new C++11 ?

Comment: If you don't see the point of move semantics, you don't understand them.

Comment: @Xeo ok, can you explain how this can improve the management of a data structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason RValues and LValues were introduced is it can be much faster to move object data than it is to perform a copy on it.  The performance gain is mainly because of internally stored pointers that do not need to be replicated during a move, which would otherwise involve needless malloc calls and memcpys.  For instance, `std::string` contains a pointer to a `char` array that can be very large.  Copying it would involve copying the data in that `char` array, moving simply involves copying the pointer to that data.

With respect to LValues and RValues, the only things, of which I'm aware, that have changed, is now we have a shiny new constructor to play with, and many of the member functions have been rewritten to take advantage of move semantics.

For instance, `std::vector` now has a `std::vector::vector(std::vector&& move)` ctor, and functions like `push_back` have been changed to also accept RValues.

This should be, for the most part, seemless to you.  If you're writing a library, rather than just using one, you need to know this, and URefs too.

Comment: so, for example ordering a data structure it's the same for a C++03 and C++11 data structure ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ordering".

Comment: for example i can expect the same performance for a map in C++11 which is a data structure that keeps its own elements oredered by key ?

Comment: `std::map::emplace` is new in C++11, and its performance is different than `std::map::insert` (usually faster, possibly significantly so).  Returning a `map` by `move` is going to have night and day performance differences: which can happen automagically if you are lucky.

Comment: what documents covers new C++11 data structures ?

Comment: @user1824407: The C++ Standard (in general) covers both the language itself as well as the Standard Library; therefore the C++11 edition covers the C++11 containers. You can check it out on github (but Latex may not be so readable) or you can refer to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) which is generally accurate.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the containers' descriptions at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), which explains the interface of STL. There, you can find what the C++11 standard adds - it is marked with '`(since C++11)`' tag. If you click on a container type, it will show you which methods are new for it.

Comment: I'm more interested in what C++11 improves or has changed from the past, that's why i was talking about map, vector and all the usual standard containers.

Comment: And that is what the link shows - if you look around you will see which methods are added in C++11 - for example, in the page for `vector`, you can see that there is a method `emplace` with a tag next to it - `(C++11)`. This means that it is added in C++11.